# SQL FileStream Opening XPS FIle

Tags: filestream, xps, documentviewer

I am trying to read an XPS file that I have inserted into my database using the Filestream attribute. Here is my code thus far.

```
        RewardsDataContext dx = new RewardsDataContext();
        var img = (from c in dx.RwProductsTests
                   select c).FirstOrDefault();
        byte[] buffer = img.Blob.ToArray();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        ms.Position = 0;

        Package package = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        XpsDocument MyDoc = new XpsDocument(package);
        dv1.Document = MyDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
        dx.Dispose();
```

and I get the following error.
XpsDocument URI is null. Use XpsDocument constructor that takes URI parameter.

Comment: ever found a solution to this?

Comment: Honestly don't recall its been awhile. I can't think of a reason why I would need an xps document anymore. Most all of the images I store, I convert them to jpg first then store them. Even if I have to build a collection afterward it still works fine.

Comment: OK. i managed this in the end. if anyone's interested, ill gladly post the answer here